# How can you make the latest Attoparsec match strings in a case-insensitive way?

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

attoparsec 0.72 had this function but it seems to have disappeared in later versions:

```
stringTransform :: (ByteString -> ByteString) -> ByteString -> Parser ByteString
```

"Match a literal string, after applying a transformation to both it and the matching text. Useful for e.g. case insensitive string comparison."

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.7.2/docs/Data-Attoparsec.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`stringCI`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.11.1.0/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString-Char8.html#v%3astringCI) from `Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8`. Consider switching to `Text` if you want the comparison to be Unicode-aware (e.g. so that "ß" is treated as equal to "ss").

Comment: @dan Note that, if you do switch to `Text`, you should use `asciiCI` rather than `stringCI`; [the latter is now deprecated (for `Text` streams)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.0.0/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Text.html#g:11).